# shinken/nagios discriminative between warning alert and critical alert

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

i using shinken for my monitoring system. Now, i have a problem when i configure shinken notification. My purpose is to discriminative between notification for warning state and critical state of check service:

with warning state:
+ time to send alert from 8h => 18 h everyday, via email and sms 
+ notification_interval is 60 minutes (Re-notify about service problems every hour)

with critical state:
+ time to send alert : all time (24 x 7), via email and sms
+ notification_interval is 30 minutes

Please show me how to solve my problem!

I have tried the following:

i configured:

```
+ contact templates:


            define contact{
                    name                            warning-contact         ; The name of this contact template
                    register                        0                       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL CONTACT, JUST A TEMPLATE!
                    host_notifications_enabled      1
                    define contact{
                service_notifications_enabled   1
                    email                           shinken@localhost
                    can_submit_commands             1
                    notificationways                email_warning, sms_warning
                    }


            define contact{
                    name                            critical-contact         ; The name of this contact template
                    register                        0                       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL CONTACT, JUST A TEMPLATE!
                    host_notifications_enabled      1
                    service_notifications_enabled   1
                    email                           shinken@localhost
                    can_submit_commands             1
                    notificationways                email_critical, sms_critical
                    }

+ time poriod templates:           
define timeperiod{
        timeperiod_name warning
        alias           Normal Work Hours
        monday          08:00-18:00
        tuesday         08:00-18:00
        wednesday       08:00-18:00
        thursday        08:00-18:00
        friday          08:00-18:00
        saturday        08:00-18:00
        sunday          08:00-18:00
        #exclude                24x7
        }

define timeperiod{
        timeperiod_name                 24x7
        alias                           24_Hours_A_Day,_7_Days_A_Week
        sunday                          00:00-24:00
        monday                          00:00-24:00
        tuesday                         00:00-24:00
        wednesday                       00:00-24:00
        thursday                        00:00-24:00
        friday                          00:00-24:00
        saturday                        00:00-24:00
        #exclude                        workhours
}


+ notification way templates:
        define notificationway{
                   notificationway_name            email_warning
                   service_notification_period     warning
                   host_notification_period        warning
                   service_notification_options    w
                   host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
                   notification_interval           60               ; Resend notifications every 30 minutes
                   service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email ; send service notifications via email
                   host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email    ; send host notifications via email
            }

                define notificationway{
                       notificationway_name            email_critical
                       service_notification_period     24x7
                       host_notification_period        24x7
                       service_notification_options    c,r
                       host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
                       notification_interval           30               ; Resend notifications every 30 minutes
                       service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email ; send service notifications via email
                       host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email    ; send host notifications via email
                }


                define notificationway{
                       notificationway_name            sms_warning
                       service_notification_period     warning
                       host_notification_period        warning
                       service_notification_options    w
                       host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
                       notification_interval           60               ; Resend notifications every 30 minutes
                       service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-sms ; send service notifications via sms
                       host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-sms    ; send host notifications via sms
                }

            define notificationway{
                   notificationway_name            sms_critical
                   service_notification_period     24x7
                   host_notification_period        24x7
                   service_notification_options    c,r
                   host_notification_options       d,u,r,f,s
                   notification_interval           30               ; Resend notifications every 30 minutes
                   service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-sms ; send service notifications via sms
                   host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-sms    ; send host notifications via sms
            }

+ my contacts
            define contact{
                use             warning-contact
                contact_name    thanhwarn
                email           xxxx
                pager           xxxx  ; contact phone number
            }

            define contact{
                use             critical-contact
                contact_name    thanhcritical
                email           xxxxx
                pager           01689xxxx   ; contact phone number


            }

+ and  define service:  
            define service{
                    use                             generic-service
                    service_description             check_ram
                    host_name                        graphite
                    contacts                        thanhcritical, thanhwarn
                    check_command                   check_nrpe!check_ram
    }
```

but my shinken system don't send alert. i don't understand this. 
please show me where I went wrong! thanks all!

Comment: can you send a mail to those addresses manually? Did this ever work?

Comment: the first, thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: the first, thanks so much for your answer! My previous shinken system working and send alerts to normal. after configured as above, my shinken system have not sent sms and email alert. :(